# Using Runtime Java to execute command in linux not working Return Code not 0

Tags: java, linux, runtime

I have a command like

```
cp -R Folder1/* Folder2/
```

or

```
rm -r /images/*.gif
```

It is not working to I try to run a sample program through Java

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
return proc.waitFor();
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have permissions to copy/remove files under these directories? Anyway, I would do it in java. You have all the classes needed to copy/remove files, so there is no point for doing it system-dependent.

Comment: yes I made sure RWX permission is present for user/group/all.
I believe when you have to move files in number of 10000 this method will be more better than using any java classes? plz correct me if am wrong..

Answer (score 0):

When you run a process, Java creates three outputs, the exit code, the STDOUT, and the STDERR. A good program running an external process, will check all three.

You are just waiting for the process to terminate, and return the exit code.

An easy way to see what's happening is to 'inherit' the STDOUT/STDERR streams [using a ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
ProcessBuilder pbuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cp", "-R", "Folder1/*", "Folder2/");
pbuilder.inheritIO();
Process proc = pbuilder.start();
return proc.waitFor();
```

you will get a better idea of what went wrong.

Note also that I used separate String arguments for the command. This helps with ensuring the arguments are passed right to the underlying process.

Comment: I have tried this as well. It gives me file directory does not exist but I when just copy and run through terminal it works...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
cmd.add("bash");
cmd.add("-c");
cmd.add(" rm -rf *.txt");
```

add the above list in ProcessBuilder then execute.